# Is there a way to make RSPec's error messages be more insightful?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, verbosity, rspec-rails

I am often at a loss when trying to debug, since RSpec only tells me that

```
expected redirect to "/user_session/new", got no redirect
expected success? to return true, got false.
```

but since It doesnt tell me what happened instead its hard to debug,

so is this something built in to RSpec and cannot be changed or is it a configuration thing of some kind.

Comment: What doesn't it tell you? It says "got no redirect"?

Comment: What happened instead. Like got success, got 404, got something else. That just doesn't help very much when you are trying to identify what caused it to fail, you have to first discover what happened instead.

Comment: For example `response.should be_success` returns false when its gets a `201 created` but just says it was false. confused the hell out of me as to why it was failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test frameworks generally permit you to assert that an actual result is equal to an expected result, and when that assertion fails, will print out the assertion as well as the expected and actual results.

There's not much more they can do. What you seem to be looking for is magical intuition on the part of software.

Try something like:

```
response.status_code.should == 200
```

This compares the actual `status_code` with the expected `status_code`, asserting their equality, and printing both if the assertion fails.

Comment: i ended up using a RegEx `response.status =~ /\A2\d\d/` more flexible, not as pretty. THanks!